# how to get android:apikey

Tags: android, android-maps

How to get the android:apikey for googlemap com.google.android.maps.MapView. i searched it but could not understand any of the articles. can someone please explain me how to get that key. thankyou

Comment: check out this link .hope this will help you http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in command prompt set your jdk path ...

like,

> C:/program files/java/jdk6/bin>

type

> keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Gaurang.android\debug.keystore"

and check you debug.keystore path and hit as a below...

> C:/program files/java/jdk6/bin >keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey
>   -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Samir\ .android\debug.keystore"

`and android as a password`

then copy `MD5 Figerprint` and add go to below link...

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

[Get-Map-Apikey](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-map-api-key.html)

Comment: Key identfier [0000: something 0010:FA 30 D2 F6] this thing???... which of these is the fingerprint???

Comment: try to search `certificate figerprint and check MD5`

Answer (score 2):

go to jdk path using command prompt :

```
cd java\jdk1.6.0.21\bin
```

then execute keytool command using this :

```
keytool.exe -list -keystore "c:\Documents and Settings\admin\.android\debug.keystore"
```

then android as password: and press enter , you ll get your api key

Answer (score 1):

Basic Requirement is to have android-sdk and java. You will be needed debug.keystore.

Now the Following is a website which will give you A to Z info..

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android.

> You can usually find the Keytool.exe from the "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\YOUR VERSION\bin" folder

Keytool.exe will help you in Generating MD5 fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

signup link for android map api key 'https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup' is not working.

showing 'Could not connect to remote server' in iframe above the fotter of the page.did any one worked on it recently?

Comment: hey i got key at '
http://t3g-garrett.appspot.com/code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html'